# Add icons to the tabs of a Firemonkey TTabControl

Tags: delphi, icons, tabcontrol, firemonkey, firemonkey-fm2

To add an icon to a TButton in Firemonkey one can add a TImage to the button. But how to add an icon to a tab of a TTabControl? Is this possible?

Comment: At the very least you'll need to modify the style (to add the image) and probably create a custom control descended from TTabControl to set the image data.

Comment: Thanks, this did it. For now I only copied the TTabItem style, assigned a different icon to the style copies and assigned the new styles to the tab items. Please post your comment again as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least you'll need to modify the style (to add the image) and probably create a custom control descended from TTabControl to set the image data.